# Why do we write test cases?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, testcase

So I know you might say, this is not a good question and a simple search can give me my answer, but it is not true. I have read a lot about testing and its importance. I know writing test cases helps to find the potential errors while programming. Also when you read the books they all are just repeating the same abstract definition. But after writing a lot of test cases, I came to this conclusion that it is not that much helpful neither preventing the potential errors nor increasing the product quality.

So just imagine we have a test case as below over a bunch of our functions:

```
Assert.IsTrue(divideNumbers(4,3) == 1);
Assert.IsTrue(divideNumbers(4,2) == 2);
Assert.AreEqual(divideNumbers(8, 4), 2);
Assert.That(divide(10,2), Eq(5))
```

So, while writing a test case, normally we are trying to assert the truthfulness of a bunch of very basic issues like Are two equations true? Is the result of this function equal to a desired result? Are they equal? Does it fail? Is an object an instance of a specified class?,.......

I have worked in a lot of software development teams. Almost in all the times and in all the teams, after writing some test cases we encounter a situation where we see the functions of **Assert Class** can't help us since they are very basic while the errors normally raises in a specific situations that are not a matter of being true, being equal, not being null,....

So, why do really write test cases? Why we really need them and how they can help us increasing the product quality and decreasing the potential errors?

Comment: If your test cases are not useful, write better tests!

Comment: Are you asking why write unit tests as opposed to integration tests or why write tests at all?

Comment: How? What is a good testcase?

Comment: I am asking, exactly why we write the Test?

Comment: I thought the same thing yesterday. Tests are no near useful as checking stuff inline in the code. Maybe messy but actually does something instead of pretend and look pro.

Answer (score 0):

The reason to write unit tests is combinatorics. Imagine your functions as nodes in a graph and calls between functions as edges. The `main` is the source node and the functions that terminate the program are destination nodes. The number of different behaviors your program can exhibit is equal to the number of paths from the source node to any destination node. This is exponential in the number of nodes and edges. This means that **it is infeasible to test all the different behaviors your program can exhibit**. This is where unit tests come in. Each unit test tests one node (calling a function with a specific input yields the expected output) or one edge (calling a function with a specific input generates a function call to the neighboring function) of the graph. The number of tests then required is just `O(|V|+|E|)`.

This has the limitation that you won't be able to catch bugs that are expressed only when a specific path is executed and are not expressed when a single function is called. This limitation is why it is important to write self contained functions with as little coupling as possible with other functions.

Answer (score 0):

> Almost in all the times and in all the teams, after writing some test cases we encounter a situation where we see the functions of Assert Class can't help us since **they are very basic** while the errors normally raises in a specific situations that are not a matter of being true, being equal, not being null,....

You have said it yourself. Basic `Asserts` are usually used in unit tests or simple tests or whatever you call them. That is, they are generally used to validate the output of some simple method or make sure that variable over there stays in between that minimum and maximum allowed values. You can't expect from an Assert to validate if some web service result contains the data you want.

> the errors normally raises in a specific situations that are not a matter of being true, being equal, not being null

Healthy testing is directly related to modularity of your code. In a properly designed code, testing would be much easier and you would not end up trying to find workarounds for testing a specific code part. Maybe what you are experiencing could be solved with a better software design approach.

> So, why do really write test cases? Why we really need them and how they can help us increasing the product quality and decreasing the potential errors?

You don't have to test your program. There are so many codes written without a single test and they can do the job too. Though properly tested code makes people happy for obvious reasons that are mentioned in tons of testing books, tutorials etc.

Answer (score 0):

what do you do when you write code without tests? after almost every change you run the whole application, you wait until it starts, you go to the page you've just changed, you input some data, you press the button and you check... if the answer is correct, if the popup appeared, if the mail was sent and so on. you DO test. but you just do it manually. and you repeat all those tests after every change. and if you don't repeat them then you will find bugs on production and you will have to correct them quickly under stress and you will have to again check if you've fixed them correctly. and you will have to do it manually...

so instead of repeating it after every change, just write VALUABLE tests, run them quickly, fix bugs and go home earlier.

this way or another you DO test. at the beginning it just seems that automatic testing requires more time because you have to write more code